# How do you align multiple empheq boundary conditions?

Tags: subequations

I am looking to align my curly brackets on the slide but cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried grouping an align statement around each as such:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{subequations}
    &\begin{empheq}[left =\text{Solar Surface =}\empheqlbrace]{alignat = 2}
    & \uvec{v}=\uvec{v}_\odot, & &\text{for} \ r=r_\odot \\
    & \uvec{B}=\uvec{B}_\odot &\quad & \text{for}\ r=r_\odot
    \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\begin{subequations}
    &\begin{empheq}[left =\text{Critical Distance =} \empheqlbrace]{alignat = 2}
    & \uvec{v}=\uvec{v}_c, & &\text{for} \ r=r_c \\
    & \uvec{B}=\uvec{B}_c &\quad & \text{for}\ r=r_c
    \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\begin{subequations}
    &\begin{empheq}[left =\text{Infinte Distance =} \empheqlbrace]{alignat = 2}
    & \uvec{v}\to\uvec{0}, & &\text{for} \ r\to\infty \\
    & \uvec{B}\to\uvec{0} &\quad & \text{for}\ r\to\infty
    \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please only ask one question per question?

Comment: I would not use equation numbers in presentations and then just use the `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` syntax in an ordinary `align*` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the need for numbering - something that doesn't really help with a presentation - using a single `align*` and some `cases` works without problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\underline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
  \text{Solar Surface} &= \begin{cases}
    \uvec{v} = \uvec{v}_\odot, & \text{for $r = r_\odot$} \\
    \uvec{B} = \uvec{B}_\odot  & \text{for $r = r_\odot$}
  \end{cases}
  \\
  \text{Critical Distance} &= \begin{cases}
    \uvec{v} =\uvec{v}_c, & \text{for $r = r_c$} \\
    \uvec{B} =\uvec{B}_c  & \text{for $r = r_c$}
  \end{cases}
  \\
  \text{Infinte Distance} &= \begin{cases}
    \uvec{v} \to \uvec{0}, & \text{for $r \to \infty$} \\
    \uvec{B} \to \uvec{0}  & \text{for $r \to \infty$}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```